# How to patch a macro with options inside another macro with options?

Tags: expl3, patching

In order to place the hyperlinks at the right place, I would like to patch a few format macros produced by `cleveref`. For example, `\cref@theorem@format` is defined as:

```
macro:#1#2#3->#2\cref@theorem@name \nobreakspace #1#3
```

I would like to replace the `#2\cref@theorem@name` into something like `A #2 B`, but this replacement should take place in another macro (say `\PatchCrefFormat`), which takes the name of the environment `theorem` as its argument.

How can this be done? I'm looking for `expl3` method (like `\regex_replace_once`) or using `regexpatch`.

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[nameinlink]{crefthe}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

% \usepackage{regexpatch}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}

% \crefthename{theorem}[le]{théorème}[les]{théorèmes}
% \Crefthename{theorem}[Le]{théorème}[Les]{théorèmes}
\crefname{theorem}{théorème}{théorèmes}
\Crefname{theorem}{théorème}{théorèmes}


\NewDocumentCommand \PatchCrefFormat { m }
% #1 is the name of an environment
{
    % In the command \cref@#1@format ,
    % how to replace the "##2\cref@#1@name" into "A ##2 B"?
}


\begin{document}


\makeatletter

\meaning\cref@theorem@format


\meaning\crefrange@theorem@format

\meaning\Crefrange@theorem@format@first

\meaning\Crefrange@theorem@format@second

\makeatother


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\show\cref@theorem@format` says `> \cref@theorem@format=\long macro:#1#2#3->\crefthemark {le}#2théorème #1#3`; no `\cref@theorem@name` in there

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Oh, my apology, I commented the existed patch in my local version of `crefthe`. Anyway I am just asking the way to do such a replacement, the actual content doesn't matter here.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I have corrected my MWE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't easily do that with `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` because you're doing it in the definition of another macro, and `\patchcmd` does a special treatment on `#`.

One way to do that replacement with `regexpatch` is:

```latex
\exp_args:Nc \regexpatchcmd { cref@#1@format }
  { \cP. 2 \c{cref@#1@name} }
  { A \ \cP\#2 \ B }
  { } { \PatchFailed }
```

The search-for regex `\cP. 2 \c{cref@#1@name}` looks for a parameter token (`\cP`) with any character code (`.`), followed by the number `2`, then a control sequence `\c{cref@#1@name}` (here `#1` is already replaced by, say, `theorem` by TeX's parameter replacement).

Then the replacement regex is simply `A \ \cP\#2 \ B`: `A`, a space, a parameter character `#` (`\cP\#`), another space, and `B`.

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[nameinlink]{crefthe}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}

% \crefthename{theorem}[le]{théorème}[les]{théorèmes}
% \Crefthename{theorem}[Le]{théorème}[Les]{théorèmes}
\crefname{theorem}{théorème}{théorèmes}
\Crefname{theorem}{théorème}{théorèmes}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \PatchCrefFormat { m }
  {
    \exp_args:Nc \regexpatchcmd { cref@#1@format }
      { \cP.2 \c{cref@#1@name} }
      { A \ \cP\#2 \ B }
      { } { \PatchFailed }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\PatchCrefFormat{theorem}

\meaning\cref@theorem@format

\meaning\crefrange@theorem@format

\meaning\Crefrange@theorem@format@first

\meaning\Crefrange@theorem@format@second

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Please allow me to ask a further question: if `A` and `B` are some token lists received as additional arguments, is it possible to make them verbatimly so as not to be recognized as regex?

Comment: @Jinwen You can write `\u{l_name_of_a_tl}`

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, if `A` is `#2`, I need to `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}`, and then use it like `\u{l_tmpa_tl}`? (I think this approach is wrong because it is the macro instead value being passed, but don't know what is the correct method)

Comment: @Jinwen Yeah, storing `#2` in a `<tl var>` then using it in `\u` also works (I didn't know that :).  You can also write `#2` (as in argument number 2) as `\cP\#2`, if that's what you're asking.  And yes, `\u` takes the _name_ of a token list, and inserts that token list in the patched macro